# Input lag and repeated letters in Atom 1.19.2 x64

Tags: arch-linux, lag, atom-feed

I have large amounts of input lag and even repeated letters (e.g. "rrrrow") in Atom.

I use Atom 1.19.2 x64 from AUR on Arch Linux 4.12.8-2-ARCH on a Ryzen 7 1700.
https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/7481 suggests safe mode but the problem persists in safe mode and even when I move the `~/.atom` folder.

How can I find the reason for this slowness and fix it?

Update: I deinstalled Atom 1.19.2 from AUR package `atom-editor-bin` and installed 1.18.0 from the official `atom` package. This temporarily increased the performance but after a few hours it is slow again.

P.S.: The issue persists in 1.23.1-1 and through a CPU upgrade and Linux reinstall. While I don't have repeated letters anymore and the input lag is ok, scrolling is still extremely sluggish. In Windows 10 this problem does not occur.

P.S.: Here is the timecop outout of safe mode:
[image]

Comment: Some of these problems were addressed in [Atom 1.22.0](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/9544). See also  [package-cop](https://atom.io/packages/package-cop) for
finding a package causing an error by logging errors.

Comment: @harrymc: Oh sorry I thought the comment didn't apply to my problem because I already added at January 6 that I already use version 1.23.1-1 but I overlooked the package-cop part, I will try this now.

Comment: @harrymc: But doesn't safe mode disable all packages?

Comment: P.S.: I tried `package-cop` but it doesn't work (clicking on "Reload Atom" does nothing).

Answer (score 1):

It [seems like](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/15467) downgrading to version 1.19.0 or below fixes the problem.

Apparently a bug was introduced into the scrolling logic ([link](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/15567#issuecomment-342249910)).
I quote the comment by Ben3eeE :

> If I understand everything correctly. We changed the scroll handler to use deltaX/Y instead of wheelDeltaX/Y and it's not the same value. wheelDelta is always +/-120 on Linux and delta is +/-53 for me right now. This change would explain why we are seeing a difference on all platforms in 1.19.
>
> atom/src/text-editor-component.js
>
> Line 1513 in 05fc82c
>
> ```
>     let {deltaX, deltaY} = event
> ```
>
> atom/src/text-editor-component.coffee
>
> Line 419 in 1f068bd
>
> ```
>     {wheelDeltaX, wheelDeltaY} = event
> ```
>
> While not the preferred solution of completely honouring the settings in the OS for the best native experience it seems like we can go back to the previous behaviour that was a better default?

Comment: Sorry, this is a different problem. My scrolling is slow because it is very laggy, the bug you found just decreases the scrolling sensitivity (so the bug makes it slow but still smooth).

Comment: This bug does the scroll in too-small increments. If you keep on scrolling, you will then have a queue of commands and a lag. The basic reason is that the Atom display is slow about which there have been many complaints. For version 1.18.0 - does the lag disappear if you restart Atom?

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be no working <= 1.19.0 Atom release for Arch Linux available anymore. The only one I found was https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/atom-editor-transparent/ but that couldn't be installed due to the checksums being faulty.

Comment: You might try instead the newest version [1.24.0-beta3](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases). You can also find here version [1.19.0](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.19.0) or even [1.18](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.18.0).

Comment: I just upgraded from Atom 1.23.2-1 to 1.23.3-1 and the problem still persists. I also tried 1.24-beta3 with no luck. I cannot run the old versions you linked because they are not available for with my package managers (pacman and yaourt).

Comment: You can try to download them from the above links and install manually. I believe Arch Linux can install .deb packages - [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83540/installing-a-deb-package-on-arch-is-it-possible), although I cannot vouch that these old packages will work for you - you will need to try and see. It would also be better to uninstall a later version before installing an older one.

Comment: Note: You bounty will soon be lost, but do as you like.